# Cannot complete sql server 2005/sql express 2005 installation in my system

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
  I am trying to install sql server 2005 in my system after uninstalling a previous version of corrupted sql server 2005. But while starting to install sql server services during installation process an error is occurring. The error is as follows:
```

**Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Setup The SQL Server service 
failed to start. 
For more information, see the SQL Server Books Online 
topics, "How to: View SQL Server 2005 Setup Log Files" and "Starting SQL Server 
Manually."
Error Number :29503**

I also tried to install SQL express 2005 results in same error..

My system configuration is as follows:

```
  1. OS->windows xp sp3
  2. processor intel atom
```

Any one please help me to get rid of this error.......

Comment: and error in the log is...? "How to: View SQL Server 2005 Setup Log Files"

Answer (score 1):

SQL 2005 will not install on a stock SP3 system.  It relates to MSXML 6.0, and the versions installed by SQL2005 and SP3.  See [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968749).

The normal fix is to use the Windows Installer Clean-up utility to remove the references to MSXML 6; unfortunately, Microsoft has removed that tool from their website.

Is there a reason you have to use SQL 2005?  If not, just go to SQL Express 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your PC is not a domain member? 
If that's the case, you can try creating an empty REG_SZ value named **Domain** in *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters* of your registry.
Then try to start SQL Server (any edition) again.

Or may be http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/920114 will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you can find your error logs you'll get an idea of what the problem is.  They can be found in: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt

This can sometimes happen if you're installing SQL Server 2005 on a system with multicore processors.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954835/en-us

Also which version and SP of SQL 2005 have you tried installing?